# WPF Validators like the one in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, wpf, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

How do we implement Validators in WPF application similar to the ASP.NET application like required field validator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And any special type validator for PasswordBox ?