# How can I restrict the values a user enters into TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Users of my application can enter values into TextBoxes. In some cases the values need to be restricted to a certain range, e.g. 0 to 1, or 1 to 50. In other cases they can only enter upto 13 or 20 characters depending.

Can I use Binding.StringFormat to enforce these ranges? If so,

- what do I need to specify to restrict values to a certain character length?
- what do I need to specify to restrict values to a certain range?

If not, what's the best way to implement this?

Comment: Why not just use a Slider control for the numeric values?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is input validation.
For starters [this tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962.aspx) will help you, more information on IDataErrorInfo (preferred way) [can be obtained here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/10/02/data-validation-in-3-5.aspx).

This question was already a topic on SO: [WPF Data Binding and Validation Rules Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646/wpf-data-binding-and-validation-rules-best-practices)

Comment: That sounds like something completely different - IMO there is difference between notifying input is not valid and disallowing invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

The [Vaildation in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation) Code Project should give you a good start.

Also the related question [WPF Validators like ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622333/wpf-validators-like-the-one-in-asp-net) should assist.

Comment: I agree with Joshua Drake. Use Validation. 

I have an example of how to do the Validation for you.
http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/02/03/how-to-disable-a-button-on-textbox-validationerrors-in-wpf/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Input mask, Check out this article [WPF Maskable TextBox for Numeric Values](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34228/WPF-Maskable-TextBox-for-Numeric-Values)

Based on this article in Events `TextBox_PreviewTextInput` and `TextBoxPastingEventHandler` you could check for a range.

Answer (score -1):

The text box length property should solve

```
Textbox.maxlength= 10;
```